# Trying to replace some text in a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have some text:

```
<p style="font-family: arial narrow;font-size: 11;font-style: normal;">
{<span data-scaytid="11" data-scayt_word="APP_PRVRIYTable" style=
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">APP_IRVRIYTable}</span></p>
```

I need to convert it to:

```
<p style="font-family: arial narrow;font-size: 11;font-style: normal;">
<span></span></p>
```

I am starting to think around "replace" and "substring" functions, but wondering whether there is a eloquent way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably best to parse this string as XML or HTML and use conventional DOM methods.

Comment: Use an html parser. For ex, HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I am using TidyManaged which is a wrapper around HtmlTidy so perhaps I have missed something. In its present setup it is not stripping this out hence my discovery of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the following would do the trick,

In your string , i think Remove will be the best option, else write your own function to do the job

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length - YourLastLettersCount);
```

or

```
 Substring()
```

or

```
 Replace()
```

Looping through the string and using  StringBuilder  to create a new string could be faster